Plotly Chlorepath Map Subplot
I have geopandas dataframe as show below. I want to create subplots where each subplot would have a map.
I managed to do a Single plot using plotly express
p4 = px.choropleth(s_new_cp, geojson=s_new_cp.geometry, color = "usage", locations = s_new_cp.index)
p4.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible = False)

But can't get it to work using subplot. How can I plot maps within subplots ?
p5 = make_subplots(rows = 1, cols = 2, specs = [[{"type":"mapbox"},{"type" :"mapbox"}]])
p5.add_trace(go.Choroplethmapbox(
    geojson=s_new_cp.geometry,
    locations = s_new_cp.index,
    z = s_new_cp.usage
), row = 1, col = 1)

>>> TypeError: Object of type Polygon is not JSON serializable

DataFrame : s_new_cp
print(s_new_cp)

    area    new usage   n_obs   y   estimate    geometry
0   BARINGO 1   0.347646    0   0   0.000000    POLYGON ((35.7839 1.65557, 35.78496 1.65554, 3...
1   BOMET   1   0.816969    0   0   0.000000    POLYGON ((35.4736 -0.3992, 35.47845 -0.40663, ...
2   BUNGOMA 1   0.465844    29  29  0.227280    POLYGON ((34.62017 1.10228, 34.62133 1.1016, 3...
3   BUSIA   1   0.713608    40  39  0.445942    POLYGON ((34.36097 0.7773, 34.36172 0.77696, 3...
4   ELGEYO MARAKWET 1   0.168763    1   0   0.027333    POLYGON ((35.69818 1.28225, 35.69788 1.27905, ...


Note px.choropleth() uses go.Choropleth() under the hood, so you likely want to use {"type":"choropleth"} for the subplot specs and use go.Choropleth() instead of go.Choroplethmapbox().
